# Using Python to plot graphs from the mySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda, spyder

I am new to python and mySQL. Initially, I want to generate few graphs using the data which I have in mySQL database. At the end I want to generate a pdf report containing that graph. Any help/advice it will be great if you guys can point me in the right direction. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am generating graphs from a database with >10 million entries. The aggregating is mostly done by the database itself. Some operations take a lot of time, but it's ok.

The connection to the database is easy with sqlalchemy and mysqlconnector. There are many others connectors for mysql.

Here a little test script for sqlalchemy. The tables are generated in this example.

You can find more at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, BigInteger, Text, Index
from sqlalchemy.orm.scoping import scoped_session


Base = declarative_base() 
class ATestEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a_test_entity_table'

    id = Column(String(32), primary_key=True)
    astring = Column(String(32))

    aint = Column(BigInteger, default=-1)


dialect = "mysql+mysqlconnector"
username = "username"
password = "passwort"
host = "localhost"
port = "3306"
database = "tests"

dbconnector = '%s://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?charset=utf8mb4&use_unicode=0' % \
    (dialect, username, password, host, port, database, )
engine = create_engine(dbconnector)
session_factory = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False)
session_factory.configure(bind=engine)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

s = scoped_session(session_factory)
try:
    #Create a new entity
    a_obj = ATestEntity()
    a_obj.id = 'test'
    a_obj.astring = 'this is a test'
    a_obj.aint = 10
    s.add(a_obj)
    s.commit()

    #Delete a entity
    s.query(ATestEntity).filter(ATestEntity.id == 'test').delete()
    s.commit()

except:
    s.rollback()
    raise
```

The mathematical calculation outside can be done with numpy and scipy if needed.
http://www.numpy.org/
https://www.scipy.org/

The plot can be done with matplotlib. There are many examples on.
http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html 
You can generate prety diagrams too.

I am generating my reports from generated latex files. But there are many pdf libraries for python too.

It's only one way to get it done.

Comment: Thanks much appreciate it. I will definitely check this out.

Comment: Just want to clarify that I already have a database what I want to do is to plot lets say data from two columns e.g. a histogram.

Comment: You can create entities, which represent your database and you don't need to call Base.metadata.create_all(engine), which creates the tables. It's realy easy to access your database with SQLAlchemy.